# Cannot use two identical Custom Activities in the same Interaction

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

we are having an issue with using two (identical) Custom Activities in the same Interaction. The `inArguments` are passed from Journey Builder to the first Interaction in the execute request, the activity runs then passes back a 200 status code response (for the execute request) to Journey Builder, but the second Custom Activity in the workflow is never executed by Journey Builder. That is, we never receive a second execute request from Journey Builder for the second Custom Activity.

I've tested this using the [custom-activity-deskapi-node](https://github.com/sfmc-developer-advocates/custom-activity-deskapi-node) sample application with the Desk.com Create Case custom activities and these work correctly; when Contacts enter the Interaction, a new case is created in Desk.com by the first Custom Activity, then a minute later (the wait period is set to one min) a second new case is created in Desk.com by the subsequent (identical) Custom Activity.

I'm just trying to figure out why we don't receive an execute request with *our* Custom Activities.

The only difference that I can see is that we're not passing any outArguments back in our response payload to the execute request. We just return a 200 HTTP status code response. Could this be the issue? Does Journey Builder always expect to receive `outArguments` in the response payload from the execute request?

Comment: When you go into JB / Admin / Contacts, what trace messages do you see?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tested this but it worked for me.  I put two Create Case activities on an interaction at minute 0 and minute 1.  Both Desk.com cases were created.  According to my heroku logs, the execute route is being called twice.

```
heroku logs -n 200
```

You can also verify this by hitting the getActivityData route:

```
https://[your sub domain].herokuapp.com/getActivityData
```

No, JB does not always expect to receive outArguments. It will look for them if you include them in the config.json.